# Minimization of $J(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle$ on the unit sphere on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: analysis, optimization, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

I would like to show that  the minimum of $J(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle$ (where $A$ is a symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrix) on $K=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n} : F(x) = 1 -\lVert x \rVert^{2} = 0 \}$ is the eigenvector associated to the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.

To do this I use the Lagrange theorem, we now that $K$ is compact and $J$ is continuous so there exists a solution to this problem, let’s say $u$. Now from the Lagrange necessary condition we know that there exists $\lambda$ such that

$$
J’(u)(h) + \lambda F’(u)(h) = 0\quad\forall h\in\mathbb{R}^{n}
$$

Here we have $J’(u)(h) = 2\langle Au, h\rangle$ and $F’(u)(h) = 2\langle x,h\rangle$.

Thus we have

$$
\forall h\in\mathbb{R}^{n}, \langle Au -\lambda u, h\rangle = 0 \implies Au = \lambda u
$$

From this we have indeed that $u$ is the eigenvector associated to $\lambda$. However I do not see how to prove that $\lambda$ is the smallest egeinvalue of $A$ ?

If you have any hints (instead of full answer, in order to work a little bit by myself) do not hesitate to share it please.

Thank you

Comment: Your $K$ is unbounded, I suspect you want $F(x)=0$.

Comment: Also note that $\min\{J(x)\mid F(x)=0\} = \min_{x\neq 0} \frac{J(x)}{\|x\|^2}$

Comment: You don't need to prove anything further, you're pretty much done. As you have observed, any eigen-pair $(\lambda, u)$ is an extreme point of the Langrangian function, i.e. a local minimizer/maximizer/saddle point. All you have to do now is order the eigenvalues, and note that for $u$ an eigenvector we have $\langle u,Au \rangle = \lambda$. Also you probably missed a $=0$ in your definition of the unit sphere. Also note that a $\langle x, Ax\rangle$ is unbounded unless $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: You have shown that each KKT point corresponds to an eigenvector of $A$, and that the global minimum over the sphere is attained.  It only remains to check that KKT conditions are necessary for this problem, and evaluate the objective at each KKT point

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Very clear thank you a lot. Indeed we have for any eigenvector $x$  of $ A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\tilde{\lambda}$ that $\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\in K$ and since $u$ is a minimum of $J$ over $K$ it follows that we have $J(x) = \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^{2}}x^{t} Ax = \tilde{\lambda} \geq J(u) =\lambda$ and hence the conclusion.

Comment: @coboy You're welcome! Please, for future reference try to see if your question has already been answered (i.e. it's not a duplicate) before posting. Otherwise, add the "solution-verification" tag to hopefully deter downvoters.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Oh yes sorry ! I added the solution verification tag !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the fact that you minimize over the unit sphere and the connection between dot product and norm.
$$\langle Au,u\rangle=\langle \lambda u,u\rangle=\lambda \langle u,u\rangle=\lambda \|u\|^2 =\lambda $$

Comment: You already assume that the minimum is one of the eigenvectors - why should that be the case?

Comment: Because OP has already proven that the minimizer is an eigenvector.